# Expand many accordion groups at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following accordion (using **angular-ui-bootstrap**) inside a paginated loop of elements:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="m in results">
    <div class="stuff_in_the_middle">
        <accordion id="accordion_{{$index+((currentPage-1)*20)+1}}"  close-others="false">
            <accordion-group>
                [...stuff...]
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group>
                [...stuff...]
            </accordion-group>
            <accordion-group>
                [...stuff...]
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
        <span id="toggle_{{$index+((currentPage-1)*20)+1}}" onClick="openAllGroups">Toggle groups</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to **expand all `accordion-group` elements at once** with one click of the Toggle link. Is it possible?

Comment: Why are you not using the ng-click directive? Is there an "expanded" attribute on your accordion that you can switch on/off? You could do something like: `<button ng-click="expandall=!expandall">Expand</button>` and on your accordion: `<accordion-group expand="expandall"></accordion-group>` or if it is a class: `<accordion-group ng-class="{'expanded':expandall}"></accordion-group>`.

Comment: I just saw that you are using angular-ui-boostrap directives in your tags. Might be good to specify it also in the description! I will have a look.

Comment: @jpmorin yep thks for pointing out. Just made it clear now. If you find anything please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own collapseall directive on the accordion-groups. In this directive you can set the isOpen scope variable (created by angular-ui) to the value from your parent controller and your toggle all button.

**EDIT:** working demo here (http://plnkr.co/edit/JOOZek2QBSmxIj2pXCkK?p=preview)

**js**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.opened = false;
}])

.directive('collapseall', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        collapseall: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('collapseall', function(newval, oldval) {
          scope.isOpen = newval;
        })
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <accordion close-others="false">
        <accordion-group heading="Item 001" collapseall="opened"> 
        </accordion-group>
        <accordion-group heading="Item 002" collapseall="opened">
        </accordion-group>
        <accordion-group heading="Item 003" collapseall="opened">
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="opened=!opened">Toggle groups</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, man :) thanks. For curiosity, what does the `restrict: 'A'` do?

Comment: It is a way to restrict how your directive will be used. 'A' as an attribute <div collapseall>, 'E' as an element <collapseall>, 'C' as a class <div class="collapseall">. You can mix them together to allow multiple ways: 'AE' for attribute and element.

Comment: This isn't working for me using angular 1.2.28 and angular-ui 0.12.1. I'm getting a multidir error because of the two isolate scopes.