# angular-ui-bootstrap accordion collapse/expand all

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to create a collpase/expand all button for a set of accordions. I am using angular.js v1.2.6 and angular-bootstrap-ui 0.9.0. I haven't been able to find an example of how to do a collpase/expand all. I'm an angular novice and any advice or suggestions is appreciated.

ALSO, I should add that the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237993/expand-many-accordion-groups-at-once?rq=1) doesn't work in the newer version of angular.js (v1.0.8 vs v1.2.6) that I am using (which is a latest version at the time of this posting). In the newer version it throws an error about trying to create two isolated scopes.

Markup:

```
    <div ng-controller="myCtlr">

     <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

     <button class="btn" ng-click="section.isCollapsed = !section.isCollapsed">Toggle Sections</button>

      <accordion-group ng-repeat="section in sections" is-open="section.isOpen">
       <accordion-heading>
        <div class="accordion-heading-content" ng:class="{collapsed: section.isOpen}">
          {{section.name}}
        </div>
       </accordion-heading>
        Section content
      </accordion-group>

     </accordion>

   </div>
```

JS:

```
var theapp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.bootstrap'
])

function myCtlr ($scope) {
 $scope.isCollapsed = false;
 $scope.sections = [
    {'id': '353','otherid': '7','name': 'One','Sequence': '1'},
    {'id': '354','otherid': '8','name': 'Two','Sequence': '1'},
    {'id': '355','otherid': '9','name': 'Three','Sequence': '1'}
];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method using the `is-open` attribute.
http://plnkr.co/edit/MliW41xGJAF0Mnw4Rgu7?p=preview

Comment: Cool. I figured out basically the same thing using the Collapse directive with the isCollapsed attribute. Any way, this works great. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone here might also find this demo I just created for manually setting an active accordion group. http://plnkr.co/edit/CD5156TaFlL365HBcyrJ?p=preview

Comment: The plunker in this solution doesn't necessarily work the way I'm interpreting the use case. When you click just a single header, they all toggle open which is not the desired affect (IMO). Only the 'toggle all' button should toggle them all, otherwise, what's the point of having the toggle all button?

Answer (score 8):

I've taken Blowsie's plunkr comment and built my own answer that solves the use case that I'm reading into here.

I've moved the close-others attribute to the accordion element where the docs say it goes. I've also added extra buttons to openAll, closeAll or toggleAll.

If you click the header for a single item, only that item opens. If you click a 'All' button, all are affected.

Thanks to Blowsie for the inspiration. I think using the item.open here was the ticket. After that, it's just a matter of affecting all item.open values.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WUKEfcBrSf3XrIQAik67?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">

  <accordion close-others="false">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in items" is-open="item.open" heading="{{item.name}}">
      {{item.open}}
      <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>

  <button ng-click="openItem(0)">Open 1</button>
  <button ng-click="openItem(1)">Open 2</button>
  <button ng-click="openItem(2)">Open 3</button>
  <button ng-click="openAllItems()">Open All</button>
  <button ng-click="closeAllItems()">Close All</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleAllItems()">Toggle All</button>
  <br/>

 {{items |json}}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'Item 1', open: false},
    {name: 'Item 2', open: false},
    {name: 'Item 3', open: false}
  ];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
  };


  $scope.openItem = function(idx) {
    console.log(idx);
    $scope.items[idx].open = true; 
  };

  $scope.openAllItems = function(){
    $scope.items.map(function(item){
      item.open = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.closeAllItems = function(){
    $scope.items.map(function(item){
      item.open = false;
    });
  }

  $scope.toggleAllItems = function(){
    $scope.items.map(function(item){
      item.open = !item.open;
    });
  }

}
```